# How to add zeros to print according to number of digit in awk?

Tags: awk, format

I have input:

```
12
2
3
56
```

and I would like to print a word with number in first column consisting from 5 numbers. How to add zeros before this number please?

```
awk '{print "file"$1".ASC}' input > output
```

The desired output:

```
file00012
file00002
file00003
file00056
```

Comment: use a [formatted string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string): `printf("file%05d.ASC", $1)`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "file%05d\n", $1}' infile.txt 
file00012
file00002
file00003
file00056
```